# Trouble with a program

Tags: list, scheme, racket

I am doing this problem set in preparation for an exam. It's in the book. Basically it tells us to design a program that counts all occurrences of "hello" in an instance of XEnum.v2.
Everything works perfectly except this problem. I am having problems with this check expect

```
(check-expect (count-in-xitem xitem3) 3)
```

it says it expects a non-empty list, but given 'ol. It should absolutely give me 3. Why does it keep telling me it expects a non-empty list?  I dumbfounded and can't figure out why.

```
  ;; An XEnum.v2 is one of:
    ;; – (cons 'ol [List-of XItem.v2])
    ;; – (cons 'ol (cons [List-of Attribute] [List-of XItem.v2]))

;; An XItem.v2 is one of:
;; – (cons 'li (cons XWord empty))
;; – (cons 'li (cons [List-of Attribute] (cons XWord empty)))
;; – (cons 'li (cons XEnum.v2 empty))
;; – (cons 'li (cons [List-of Attribute] (cons XEnum.v2 empty)))

;; A XWord is '(word ((text String)))

;; An Attribute is
;; - (cons Symbol (cons String empty))

(define xword1 '(word ((text "hello"))))
(define xword2 '(word ((text "Hello"))))
(define attr1 (cons 'Symbol (cons "hello" empty)))
(define attr2 (cons 'Symbol (cons "elo" empty)))

(define xitem1 (cons 'li (cons xword1 empty)))
(define xitem2 (cons 'li (cons (list attr1 attr2) (cons xword1 empty))))
(define xe1 (cons 'ol (list xitem1 xitem2))) ;; 3
(define xe2 (cons 'ol (cons (list attr1 attr2) (list xitem2 xitem1))))
(define xitem3 (cons 'li (cons xe1 empty))) ;; 1
(define xitem4 (cons 'li (cons (list attr1 attr2) (cons xe1 empty))))



;; X-Item.v2 -> Number
;; returns number of "hello" occurences in an X-Item.v2
(define (count-in-xitem xi)
  (cond
    [(is-xword? (second xi)) (count-in-xword (second xi))]
    [(is-xenum? xi) (+ (count-in-xitem (second xi))
                       (count-in-xitem (second (rest xi))))]
    [(is-attribute? (first (second xi))) (+ (count-in-loa (second xi))
                                            (count-in-xword (first (rest (rest xi)))))]

    [else (+ (count-in-loa (second xi))
             (occurrences (second (rest xi))))]))

;; tests for count-in-xitem function
;(check-expect (count-in-xitem xitem1) 1)
;(check-expect (count-in-xitem xitem2) 2)
;(check-expect (count-in-xitem xe1) 3)
(check-expect (count-in-xitem xitem3) 3)




;; XWord -> Natural
;; returns 1 if string is "hello"
(define (count-in-xword x) 
  (if (string=? (second (first (first (rest x))))
                "hello")
      1
      0))

;; tests for count-in-xword function
(check-expect (count-in-xword xword1) 1)
(check-expect (count-in-xword xword2) 0)


;; [List-of Attribute] -> Natural
;; returns 1 if occurrences of "hello" in the list of attributes                              
(define (count-in-loa loa) 
  (foldr (λ(s b) (if (string=? (second s) "hello") (+ 1 b) b)) 0 loa))

;; tests for count-in-loa function
(check-expect (count-in-loa (list attr2)) 0)
(check-expect (count-in-loa (list attr1
                                  (cons 'b (cons "hello" empty)))) 2)



;; XEnum.v2 -> Number
;; counts all occurrences of "hello" in an instance of XEnum.v2
(define (occurrences xe)
  (if (eqv? (rest (rest xe)) empty)
      (xenum2 empty (rest xe))
      (xenum2 (second xe) (rest (rest xe)))))

;; [List-of Attribute] [List-of XItem.v2] -> Number
;; returns number of "hello" occurences
(define (xenum2 atr item)
  (+ (count-in-loa atr)
     (count-in-xitem item)))


;; tests for xenum2 function
;(check-expect (xenum2 (list attr1 attr2) (list xitem1 xitem2)) 0)


;; [List-of Any] -> Boolean
;; checks if the list is an XEnum.v2
(define (is-xenum? xe)
  (cond
    [(empty? xe) false]
    [(symbol? (first xe))
     (symbol=? (first xe) 'ol)]))


;; tests for is-attribute? function
(check-expect (is-xenum? xe1) true)
(check-expect (is-xenum? xe2) true)
(check-expect (is-xenum? (cons 'al (list xitem1 xitem2))) false)
(check-expect (is-xenum? empty) false)


;; ATTRIBUTE
(define (is-attribute? xe)
  (and (symbol? (first xe))
       (string? (second xe))
       (not (symbol=? (first xe) 'ol))))

;; tests for is-attribute? function
(check-expect (is-attribute? attr1) true)
(check-expect (is-attribute? attr2) true)
(check-expect (is-attribute? (cons 1 (cons "hi" empty))) false)


;; XWORD
(define (is-xword? xe)
  (and (symbol? (first xe))
       (symbol=? 'word (first xe))
       (symbol=? 'text (first (first (second '(word ((text String)))))))
       (symbol=? 'String (second (first (second '(word ((text String)))))))))

;; tests for is-xword? function
(check-expect (is-xword? xword1) true)
(check-expect (is-xword? xword2) true)
(check-expect (is-xword? '(world ((text "hello")))) false)
```

I think the problem is here

```
;; ATTRIBUTE
(define (is-attribute? xe)
  (and (symbol? (first xe))
       (string? (second xe))
       (not (symbol=? (first xe) 'ol))))
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can track this problem down using the stepper.

Click the "step" button, and wait until all of the steps have been computed (you'll see the denominator stop changing in the step count). Then, choose "jump to end" from the drop-down menu. You'll see that your test case is asking for (first 'ol).  To see how this arises, step backward; I can see that you're calling is-attribute? on 'ol, but I didn't step any further back to see why this was the case.